# How to restore the missing subtick lines and missing tick labels?

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

I attempted to setup a plotting area with precisely specified subticks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0pt,12pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

% The following USER INTERFACE are intentionally defined
% to allow users to adjust the PDF output
% to conform to the constraint given by their
% teachers.
% Please don't modify this UI.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%% BEGIN OF USER INTERFACE %%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Domain of f(x)
\FPeval\XMin{0-pi/6}
\FPeval\XMax{2*pi+pi/6}
\FPeval\YMin{0-1} % We cannot use negative values directly because the author always thinks positively.
\FPeval\YMax{1}



\FPeval\xAtomicUnit{pi} % We cannot use \FPset\xAtomicUnit{pi} because pi is not a constant literal but a function.
\FPset\yAtomicUnit{1}


\FPset\xDivision{180}
\FPset\yDivision{3}


% Dx and Dy represent tick label counters.
% Example:
%   yfractionLabels=true,
%   yfractionLabelBase=10,
%   Dy=3,
% The y tick labels: 3/10, 6/10, 9/10, etc.
\FPset\Dx{30}
\FPset\Dy{2}


% dx and dy represent the distance
% between two consecutive ticks (not subticks)
\FPeval\dx{xAtomicUnit/xDivision*Dx}
\FPeval\dy{yAtomicUnit/yDivision*Dy}


\FPset\xSubTicks{3}
\FPset\ySubTicks{2}


% Extra spaces (paddings) around the domain.
\FPeval\XOL{0-3/xSubTicks}  % of dx
\FPeval\XOR{2/xSubTicks}    % of dx
\FPeval\YOB{0-1/ySubTicks}  % of dy
\FPeval\YOT{1/ySubTicks}    % of dy


\FPeval\AxisL{XMin+dx*XOL}
\FPeval\AxisR{XMax+dx*XOR}
\FPeval\AxisB{YMin+dy*YOB}
\FPeval\AxisT{YMax+dy*YOT}


\newlength\Width\Width=148.5mm


\newlength\llx\llx=-30pt
\newlength\urx\urx=15pt
\newlength\lly\lly=-5pt
\newlength\ury\ury=15pt


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%% END OF USER INTERFACE %%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\psset
{
    llx=\llx,
    lly=\lly,
    urx=\urx,
    ury=\ury,
    xsubticks=\xSubTicks,
    ysubticks=\ySubTicks,   
    algebraic,
    plotpoints=100,
}

\newpsstyle{mygrid}
{
        dx=\dx,
        dy=\dy,
        labels=none,
        xticksize=\YMin\space \YMax,
        yticksize=\XMin\space \XMax,
        subticksize=1,
        subtickcolor=Red!50,
        tickcolor=Green!50,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{psgraph}
    [
        dx=\dx,
        dy=\dy,
        Dx=\Dx,
        Dy=\Dy,
        yfractionLabels,
        yfractionLabelBase=\yDivision,
        xlabelFactor={}^\circ,
        showorigin=false,
        axespos=top,
        xAxisLabel=$x$,
        yAxisLabel=$y$,
        labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,
    ]{->}(0,0)(\AxisL,\AxisB)(\AxisR,\AxisT){\dimexpr\Width-\urx+\llx}{!}
    %--------------------------------------------------------------------   
    \psaxes[style=mygrid](0,0)(\XMin,\YMin)(\XMax,\YMax)
    \psplot[linecolor=blue]{\XMin}{\XMax}{2*sin(2*x)/3}
    %--------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, sometimes the subtick lines and tick labels near the edges are missing even though I have precisely specified the paddings to be integer multiples of  a single subtick width.

How to fix this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last right vertical line is not drawn with \psaxes, to let the arrow end right of a "tick" line. If you need this line then try `\psgrid`. However (needs package `pst-calculate`:

```
\psaxes[dx=\dx,
        dy=\dy,
        labels=none,
        xticksize=-\AxisT\space \AxisT,
        yticksize=\AxisL\space \pscalculate{\XMax+\dx/3},
        subticksize=1,
        subtickcolor=Red!50,
        tickcolor=Green!50](0,0)(\AxisL,\AxisB)(\AxisR,\AxisT)
```

[image]